# Adding onclick=window.location=mailto: where recipient is a variable in a function

Tags: javascript, function, mailto

I have a page that is used by Doctors, where they can write the patient email select a bounce of documents, and via "mailto" create a formatted email. This doesn't work on Safari iOS.

The problem I found is mailto does not work with Safari iOS if launched   from home screen (as a web app). It works using onclick=window.location I tried to implement it on my function but it is not working

so I am trying to implement something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='mailto:me@any.com?subject=Docs&body=Hallo%20you%20and%20links'; return false;" class="noHighlight">Write and email</a>
```

in my function:

```
function buildMailto(recipient, subject, body) {
  var mailToLink = "mailto:" + recipient + "?";
  var mailContent = "Subject=" + subject + "&";
  mailContent += "cc=testemail@gmail.com&";
  mailContent += "body="
  mailContent += encodeURIComponent(body);
  a.href = mailToLink + mailContent;
}
```

I am trying to edit:

```
function buildMailto(recipient, subject, body) {
var mailToLink = " '#'  onclick=\"window.location='mailto:" + recipient +"?";
  var mailContent = "Subject=" + subject + "&";
  mailContent += "cc=testemail@gmail.com&";
  mailContent += "body="
  mailContent += encodeURIComponent(body);
  mailContent +=  "return false;  class='noHighlight' ";
  a.href = mailToLink + mailContent;
}
```

Not having any results at the moment

Comment: What is your `a` defined?

Answer (score 1):

There were a few issues with your code:

- `a` was never defined. Give your link an ID and select id by using `document.getElementById()`
- You cannot set the `href` attribute of the link and "break out" using double quotes in order to add the onclick attribute to the element. Instead:
- add the `click` event using `.addEventListener()`. Alternatively, you could use `.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href = "' + mailToLink + mailContent + '"; return false;');` if you wanted to be able to see the click event using your browser's DOM inspector, but it doesn't really make sense.

  ```js
  function buildMailto(recipient, subject, body) {
  var mailToLink = "mailto:" + recipient +"?";
    var mailContent = "Subject=" + subject + "&";
    mailContent += "cc=testemail@gmail.com&";
    mailContent += "body="
    mailContent += encodeURIComponent(body);
    document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click', function() {
      window.location.href = mailToLink + mailContent;
      return false;
    });
  }

  buildMailto('foo@bar.baz', 'a subject', 'mail content');
  ```

  ```html
  <a href="#" id="myLink" class="noHighlight">Write and email</a>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In your `buildMailto` function, you didn't specify what is `a`. Instead of updating `onclick` attribute value when the anchor link is clicked, you should build a mailto URL and update `window.location.href`. Here is an example:

```
<a href="#" id="email-link" class="noHighlight">Write and email</a>
```

Event listener for anchor link:

```
document.querySelector('#email-link').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    buildMailto('me@any.com', 'Docs', 'Hi, there!');
});
```

Change your `buildMailto` to the following:

```
function buildMailto(recipient, subject, body) {
    var mailLink = "mailto:" + recipient + "?";
    mailLink += "Subject=" + subject + "&";
    mailLink += "cc=testemail@gmail.com&";
    mailLink += "body="
    mailLink += encodeURIComponent(body);
    window.location.href = mailLink;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try embedding your actionable into a form. Like this:

```
<form action="mailto:me@any.com?subject=Docs&body=Hallo%20you%20and%20links" method="GET">
  <button class="noHighlight" type="submit">Write and email</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried your snippet before posting it? The subject and body don't actually work.

Comment: I clearly made a mistake not posting all the js, sorry to everyone:

Comment: Here is a working example

https://jsfiddle.net/robmagiin/bp36u0dn/6/#&togetherjs=6fM1onpwHr

Comment: As I said this code works fine, but it fails when the page is saved on iPhone home screen. When launched from iPhone home screen it gives an error: Safari can't open the page.

To make mailto works in Safari from Homescreen  I need to use something like this: <a href="#" class="noHighlight" onclick="window.location='mailto:test@gmailcom'; return false;" >Write Email</a>

But I am failing of implementing this in the working JS